# Each slideshow image with specific button

Tags: javascript, views

I've got a Drupal website, to which I added a slideshow.
Each slideshow has to contain some text and a button.

The problem is, I don't know how to add a different link/URL to every single slideshow image.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

PS. I would not prefer adding a button programmatically. However, I'm familiar with Javascript/jQuery, in case there is no other solution

Comment: you can add link to each slide, i mean each image not button , is it ok ?

Comment: This is a very common pattern and there are countless slideshow modules on Drupal.org that implement this exact use case, why not try one of these out? https://drupal.org/node/418616